# poner blanco el label cuando hay texto en el input

Tags: html, css, input, label

tengo un formulario con un input y su label, pero no consigo con CSS poner el label blanco(o que desaparezca el texto del label) cuando hay texto en el recuadro del input:

```
          <div class="form__group field">
        <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder=" " name="ntar" id='ntar' required 
          />
        <label id="Ptarje"for="ntar" class="form__label">Ptarje</label>
      </div>
```

he intentado quitarlo poniendo color:white; en el css pero así desaparece el texto del label aunque no tenga nada escrito el input...

```
.form__field:focus {
color: white !important;
}
```

así no se ve el texto que escribo hasta que quito el focus, y si lo pongo form__label en vez de field no hace nada...

Comment: Esto es una tarea que se puede hacer con Javascript

Comment: @Ivandez depende de como se deba hacer segun el escenario del OP.

Comment: @ebsigma puedes aclarar si es con CSS o se puede implementar javascript?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer eso con css?

Comment: si creo que con `content: ' ';`

Comment: Ya me he auto respondido. Es para hacerlo con CSS ya que es mas rápido y limpio que JS

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas, al final lo que necesitaba es poner:

```
.form__field:valid + label  {
opacity: 0; 
/*color: white !important;*/
}
```

de esta forma, cuando es válido (hay texto en el campo del formulario) le digo al label, que no tenga opacidad (en vez de poner texto blanco por si hay un fondo de otro color)